# How to check existing data before inserting new data to the access table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a saloon access database. In that database I have 3 tables called "Employees", "Services", "Reservations".

**Employees Table**

```
Employee_Name |   age   |   tel
    John          28      12456325
    Bob           32      56458756
```

**Services Table**

```
Service_Name    |     HourlyPrice
head massage            50USD
foot massage            30USD
body massage            70USD
```

**Reservations Table**

```
Reservation_ID  |  Employee_Name | Service_Name | Service_Hours |     Date     |  Start_Time
      1                 John       head massage      2 hours      31/12/2020        14:00
      2                 Bob        foot massage      1 hour       31/12/2020        20:00
```

These are my database tables. If a customer want to made a reservation he/she can call the saloon and made a reservation for their free time.

For an example if a customer want John to do a head massage then he/she can call the saloon and he/she will tell the date, service hours and start time. Then the saloon receptionist will add the reservation data into the reservation table.

So the system will need to check before add the new reservation data with existing data.

Example : John will not available until 14:00 to 16:00 on 31/12/2020 because he has a 2 hours reservation. So system will prevent to add new reservations on John between 14:00 to 16:00 on 31/12/2020.

For example, if another customer wants John for a head massage on 31/12/2020 15:00. Then the system will cancel that reservation. Because in that time John will do a head massage for another customer.

**This is my vba code**

```
Private Sub check_Click()

If (DCount("Employee_Name", "Reservations", "Employee_Name=""" & [Text1].Value & """ AND [Date]=#" & [Text2].Value & "#") <> 0) Then
      MsgBox "There is a reservation for the employee in this date. Please check the time with that reservation."

Else
    MsgBox "No reservations booked in this day."
    
End If
End Sub
```

From the above code I can check Employee name and date only with the new record. But I want to check the employee name, date, start time and service hours.

I hope you will understand my situation. Please help me.

> Thanks & Regards, Zajjith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear if you book just to a day/date, or you book to a date + a particular person?

Ether way, the logic is simple.

Any kind of booking collision occurs with the following simple formula:

A collision occurs when:

```
RequestStartDate <= EndDate 
and 
RequestEndDate >= StartDate
```

The above is thus a rather simply query, but if any collision occurs, the
above will return records, and you simply don't allow the booking. In other
words, since we NEVER allow booking with a collision, then the above simply
statement will work for us.

The above will catch an attempt that spans OVER a start/end. or a span that falls inside. And in fact the above test will ALSO catch any overlap with the start or end, or ANY combination there of!!

So, some code to check for the booking slot?

Well, we assume that we use a datetime data type here. (thus we include date and time as "one type" of column. This makes things real easy - and in fact would allow bookings to cross midnight if we so please - or say span multiple days. We might be booking out a beer keg, a room, or a power drill for a few days.

```
dim strWhere                        as string 
dim dtRequeestStartDate      as date 
dim dtRequestEndDate         as date 


dtRequestStartDate = inputbox("Enter start Date") 
dtRequestEndDate = inputbox("Enter end date") 


strWhere="#" & format(dtRequestStartDate,"mm/­dd/yyyy") & "# <= EndDate" & _ 
    " and #" & format(dtRequestEndDate,"mm/dd­/yyyy") & "#  >= StartDate"
```

Now to above, would/could add a room number, or a person (say a doctor) or whatever.

And of course while i used a Inputbox, you would normally place some text boxes on a form for the user to enter. (maybe a cool nice combo box to select the employee)

And in above I used dates - but we should include date + time in that query. So, the format should (could) be changed from mm/dd/yyyy to that of

```
? FORMAT(NOW,"MM\/DD\/YYYY HH:MM")
12/28/2020 18:02
```

Also, of course in the above where clause, we would include that room number, that power tool number, or say the employee you want to book with.

```
strWhere = strWhere & " And EmployeeName = 'John'
```

As noted, it not clear if all employees can offer all services. But if John is booked in that date range - then you get records back - and you thus CANNOT make that booking.

So entry of the date now requires the user to also include the time.

Thus, with our above where clause, then we can go:

```
if dcount("*","Reservations",strW­here) > 0 then 
    msgbox "sorry, you cant book 
    ...bla bla bla....
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. 

Some extra information. In here, a employee can offer many services. I need to check the employee name, date, start time, end time (start time + service hours). So same employee can't be book on the same day within the start time and end time of the existing reservations. I hope you understand will understand me.

Comment: Then just checking per person is all that is required then. If they are booked as per above then they can't work on anything else.  So you book by date/time and person. Of course a monkey wrench would be that certain staff only offer certain services. But then again, that would simply be part of the drop down you place on the form that selects the staff. If the staff does certain services, then simply display that same staff member in the drop down for each of the services they offer. If they offer 2 or 10 different it really don't' matter since if that staff booked are not available.

Comment: Sir may you add all codes into one? Please sir I tried there are errors. Please arrange all codes into one.